# MS SQL 2000 Server slow. How to check memory usage of last week

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, out-of-memory, sql-server-2000

I have old MS SQL 2000 server. We have issue(very slow) in our web application(.Net), and we thought it is because of high memory usage in SQL Server. Because we found that (in Task manager processes) SQl server is consuming a lot of memory and becomes very slow. 
So my questions are - 
1. Do you think SQL Server issue is the cause for our application issue?
2. How do we check memory usage of SQL server for past few days.

Thanks in adavance.

Kindly do reply
Sharda

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory

Comment: I would first check the query plan cache to see if there are large amounts of similar plans. sp_BlitzCache can help identify problems.

Comment: SQL Server 2000, as I'm sure you know, has been out of support for years. Just from a security perspective, since there are web apps hitting this box, you should recommend an upgrade. If cost is a factor, there are cheap or free current RDBMSs that will perform at least as well as your 2000 box.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. Yes I agree and hence we are now looking for another database "Postgres"

Comment: Sorry for late reply